# How do I delete a specific table row in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter. How can I delete a specific table row in CodeIgniter? I tried to pass the `id` variable, but nothing happened.

This is my view:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $cell) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $cell; ?></td>               
            <?php } ?>
            <td><?php echo anchor('reports/delete_row',$this->lang->line("common_delete"),array('sale_id'=>'id')); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function delete_row()
{       
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->load->model("reports/summary_sales");
    $this->summary_sales->row_delete($id); 
}
```

This is my model:

```
public function row_delete($id){
    $this->db->delete('sales', array('id' => 'sale_id')); 
}
```

This my `var_dump($cell)`:

```
string(11) "Rp.-1980.00" string(9) "Rp.500.00"
```

This is my `var_dump($row)`:

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(1) "1" 
[1]=> string(10) "2016-01-30" 
[2]=> string(8) "Rp.20.00" 
[3]=> string(8) "Rp.20.00" 
[4]=> string(11) "Rp.-1980.00" 
} 
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(2) "13" 
[1]=> string(10) "2016-02-01" 
[2]=> string(10) "Rp.3000.00" 
[3]=> string(10) "Rp.3000.00" 
[4]=> string(9) "Rp.500.00" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the name of the field on your table?

`id` or `sale_id` ?

The problem seems to be here

```
public function row_delete($id){
     $this->db->delete('sales', array('id' => $id)); 
}

// or

public function row_delete($id){
    $this->db->delete('sales', array('sale_id' => $id)); 
}
```

EDIT: maybe the problem is in your `<a>` tag, 
seems you are not doing well the anchor, you should 
do like this and concatenate the $row[0] ( that seems to be your `id`).

**View**

```
<?php echo anchor('reports/delete_row/'.$row[0],$this->lang->line("common_delete"),array('sale_id'=>'id')); ?>
//-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^ 
//------------------------your row id goes here
```

Make sure it arrives to your controller well, I also recommend to change your controller function and add the parameter `$id`

**Controller**

```
public function delete_row($id)
{       
    //$id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->load->model("reports/summary_sales");
    $this->summary_sales->row_delete($id); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: then use the second function i posted, the problem is that you are not passing the `$id` to the function

Comment: the problem then is on the las `td` on your view, what's the value of `$id`? you are not passing any value. `array('sale_id'=>'id')` that will not work, you should use maybe `$cell` or the variable where you are storing your real id value

Comment: do you mean using $cell like this?
   array($cell['sale_id']=>'id')

Comment: the field you want to put on the where condition must be the key of the array, `array('sale_id' => 1)` . this translated will be something like this ' `WHERE sale_id = '1'`

Comment: i know what you mean but i still confused about how i gather the value of sale_id inside array $cell in view and passing it hope you know what i mean thanks

Comment: can you `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($cell)` on your view and edit your question, so we'll have more information, thanks in advance

Comment: ok i edit my question with var dump $ row and $cell now
thanks

Comment: i edited the answer, looks like the problem is near the <a> tag, try to improve that, you should concantenate on the url the `id`

Comment: glad we finally we fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. definitely it wil work

```
public function row_delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where('sale_id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('sales');
}
```

Comment: i already tried that method but still cannot delete my database
but thanks for the help

Comment: it's solved in another answer thanks for your concern

Comment: Ok Samuel Billy., always happy to help :)